# Woocommerce product images are being cropped

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, thumbnails

Here are the settings i use on the [website](https://frix-cy.com/) for the woocommerce images.

[image]

If you visit the [website homepage](https://frix-cy.com/), you will notice that the images with the 3 rows are being cropped but everywhere else they are normal. (right below in the special offers section they are okay, with the same size)

If you inspect an image and open in new tab, you will notice they are actually cropped. Those rows are created with siteorigin plugin and the widget is the product tyche widget of the theme tyche.

What could be the solution of this issue? Why the images are being cropped at those 3 rows? (Gaming, accessories, merchandise)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it was a theme issue and not Woocommerce.

Thanks to [Simple Image Sizes plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-image-sizes/), I managed to fix the issue simply by disabling cropping on all of the theme images and resizing those image to the proper size so they get the perfect quality!

Answer (score 0):

It might be the issue for different sizes of the 3 images. Try to do all the images equal size then add the pictures again. Hopefully, it will work.

Comment: but if i change the image size then all the other images of the website (that are currently okay) will change size and some will be small and some big . I have to find a solution on those 3 rows

Comment: I would say this doesn't attempt to answer the question or resolve the problem, even with a workaround, but proposes a different problem, which is frowned upon.  Fine as a comment once you have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: This plugin is broken and doesn't work anymore. Don't even try it. Waste of time.